# GNOME-keyring KWallet integration?

Tags: security, password, gnome-keyring, kwallet

I use some GNOME apps, and some KDE apps, so some of them use G-keyring and some KWallet... What I would like to have is a single place for managing passwords.

Is there a way to integrate G-keyring and KWallet? Or is there maybe a way to force GNOME apps to use KWallet or KDE apps to use G-keyring? OR is there maybe a way to force them all to use KeePassX or something similar (automaticaly using it after entering the master password)...?

Comment: I remember some talk about KDE trying to get a single API developed, with Gnome? but afaik, it has yet to be fruitful unfortunately. I'll try to look up some references later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/the-future-of-kde-718510?artc_pg=2)

> One annoyance of the free desktop at present is the use of incompatible systems for storing sensitive user data such as passwords. Every web browser may have its own password store and anyone using both KDE and Gnome applications will likely have to open both KWallet and Gnome Keyring in every desktop session.

> Michael Leupold presented a collaboration between KDE and Gnome to develop a unified standard for storing secrets. The aim is that KDE and Gnome applications will both be able to share a common secrets architecture but still have separate graphical interfaces.

> A KDE user will be presented with a KDE interface if they need to unlock an account in Empathy (the Gnome instant messaging application) while a Gnome user will see a Gnome interface for password management even if they prefer to chat using KDE's Kopete. It is also hoped that the standard will attract the support of other vendors, such as Mozilla.

[this](http://www.confuego.org/archives/21-fd.o-secret-storage-project.html) seems older, but might be a link to the [actual project?](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/secret-storage-spec)

> After having hinted at it now and then, I can finally gladly announced that we (GNOME Keyring + KDE Wallet) managed to kick off a joint freedesktop.org project with the goal of creating a common infrastructure (or more technically: protocol) for managing passwords and other secret values.

Comment: we all hope this to be implemented soon or later :)

Comment: No progress has been made for 7 years.

Comment: If at least there was a way to export and import from one to the other that would be helpful already.

Comment: I wrote a detailed reply at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/248397/255524 . Skip down to the KSecretsService section for the status update. In short, the FreeDesktop Secrets Service support has improved, including in some KDE apps, but KWallet itself is stuck behind.

Comment: After a long, long time. This should be working now in KWallet v5.97.0 - https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kwallet/-/merge_requests/11